# html button appearing as input box on form

Tags: php, html, css, forms, button

I Apologize for the simplicity of the question, still learning the ropes.

I have the following code:

```
<form action="backyard_funcs.php" method="post" id="register-form">
<input "type="submit" id="register-submit" name="register-submit" value="Create Account" />
</form>
```

My objective is to have a form that is submitted at the push of the button named register-submit. However it is not appearing as a button, instead it is appearing as an input box.

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<input type="submit"...`

Comment: Just may be a typo change your `"type="submit"` to `type="submit"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
"type="submit"
```

it should be

```
type="submit"
```

otherwise you break parsing of that `input` and default type it then falls back to is `text`

Answer (score 2):

Try using a code editor like 
**sublimetext : http://www.sublimetext.com/3**
it'll help you color any coding errors later on so easily! :)

Here's the right code for your answer:

```
<form action="backyard_funcs.php" method="post" id="register-form">
    <button type="submit id="register-submit" name="register-submit">Create Account</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Missing quotes in your button element there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input "type="submit" id=....
```

should be

```
<input type="submit" id=....
```

without the quote before `type`

Answer (score 0):

There is an ( " ) too much in your code

```
<form action="backyard_funcs.php" method="post" id="register-form">
    <input type="submit" id="register-submit" name="register-submit" value="Create Account" />
    </form>
```